# Laravel Symfony/console , installation failed because of "Invalid argument"?

Tags: php, laravel, bash, composer-php

Sorry if it seems like a nooby thing, but I am nooby at this composer/cmd thing.

I keep getting the same error while trying to install Laravel installer.
The composer resists to install "symfony/console", it downloads it, but cannot load it. Any ideas why?

Just today it was working fine, few hours in I tried to create a new project and that's what I keep getting :

```
**[ErrorException]
copy(D:\Laravel\cr\vendor/symfony/console/b9a023bcb5ec9a752e17f3
f5c1358bfc): failed to open stream: Invalid argument**
```

[image]

Since the error I've tried **reinstalling** composer, deleting all of its data from **Appdata\Roaming\Composer** folder, tried to delete vendor folder from laravel project itself and **install composer** through bash once again. **None helped**, can't find similar answer to the question either.

Comment: What is `PolyMORM#CRUD`? Where that hash sign comes from?

Comment: It has absolutely no meaning, it is just a name of folder.

Comment: It's very weird naming convention for directory name though. Hash sign usually has some [extra meaning like special character](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543242/cd-to-a-directory-has-hash) so maybe there is some collision with unix like mingw64 consolse and composer. I'd try with directory renaming for sake of it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it does not help, because at the moment (as stated in the question) I cannot install the Laravel Installer itself (the one you get with command : composer global require laravel/installer). It gets stuck at the same "symfony/console" position. The picture and text is just an example, the issue remains same either way.

Comment: Can't tell more, didn't have such an issue on homestead/vagrant/docker nor on macos/ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Windows Defender detected Trojan:Script/Foretype.A!ml on symfony/console (v5.1.7)
After i disabled the Virus Protection i was able to finish the install.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what was causing it to decline the installation! Would give rep if I was able to. :s

Comment: explain the setting for windows to remove this issue

Comment: Adding the working directory as exclusion is valid too and more secure :3

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable windows defender or other anti-virus programs; also, check you have proper permissions to the folder.

***how to disable windows defender***:

- search `setting` in windows
- click `windows security`, below you will see **virus and threat protection**
- turn off `real time protection`, then create project in laravel, it will run with zero errors

[image]

Comment: There is no need to duplicate existing answers unless you want to add something new